# Obtener un boleano de server en el client con lua

Tags: lua

Buenas quisiera saber si a través de un trigger que está en la parte de server y contiene ciertos if's, si tengo declarada la variable local vendido = false, pudiese obtener ese true/false en el apartado del client. Por ejemplo, en este código obtener en la parte del cliente el true o false. Gracias de antemano

```
RegisterServerEvent("clientes:ventas")
AddEventHandler("clientes:ventas",function(data)
     if precio>100 then
     vendido = true
     else
    vendido = false
    end
end)
```